# What's the best practice for a similar API called by Client vs User authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, api-design

In a situation where you want to get user info from an api, and you may be calling as a User (end-user) token or a Client (owned service) token, is it better to have separate endpoints, or to share an endpoint and handle the authorization within?

For example, between something like this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy ="ClientAllowedToGetUserInfo")]
        [Route("userinfo/{userId}")]
        public ActionResult<UserInfo> GetUserInfo(Guid userId)
        {           
            return GetTheUserInfo(userId);
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy ="UserCheckingOwnUserInfo")]
        [Route("userinfo")]
         public ActionResult<UserInfo> GetUserInfo2(Guid userId)
        {           
            return GetTheUserInfo(User.Identity.Name);
        }
```

or this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy ="ClientOrUser")]
        [Route("userinfo/{userId}")]
        public ActionResult<UserInfo> GetUserInfo(Guid userId)
        {           
            if User.Claims.HasClaim("MyClientClaim") || (userId == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                return GetTheUserInfo(userId);
            }
            return Forbidden();     
        }
```

What's the best practice?

Comment: I can't see any difference between the actions methods and wondering how are you going to compile them?

Comment: I've modified it prevent the duplicate name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`separate endpoints` and `share an endpoint` can all work fine. But there is a different between them. When you use `separate endpoints`, If validate fails, request will not get into the action, it just return directly in Policy. When you use `share an endpoint`, request will get into the action and validate in `if(....)`. So, in my opinion, I will choose `separate endpoints`. Because I prefer to validate in policy rather than in action